# Use AsyncLocal to store request information?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

We are starting with ASP.NET Core 2. We need a way for each element that is involved in a request to write a message to a message handler.

Some limitations:

- We won't use `HttpContext.Items` (`HttpContext` is not available in the class that we are using inside the Controller, and we don't like to forward the whole context there).
- We tried to use it without dependency injection because if we have multiple different services, we will have too many parameters in the constructors.
- Must also work with `async`/`await`.

We tried an approach using `AsyncLocal<T>`.

For that we created a class:

```
public class NotificationExecutionContext
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<NotificationHandler> NotificationHandler =
        new AsyncLocal<NotificationHandler>();

    public static NotificationHandler Instance =>
        NotificationHandler.Value ?? (NotificationHandler.Value = new NotificationHandler());
}
```

There will be a `NotificationHandler` created, which should live per-request. The `NotificationHandler` is a simple class where you can add/get messages to/from a collection:

```
public class NotificationHandler : INotificationHandler
{
    public List<NotificationBase> Notifications { get; } = new List<NotificationBase>();

    public void AddNotification(NotificationBase notification)
    {
        Notifications.Add(notification);
    }

    public void AddNotificationRange(List<NotificationBase> notifications)
    {
        Notifications.AddRange(notifications);
    }
}
```

With this solution, I can easily get the `NotificationHandler` for this context and add a notification.

```
NotificationExecutionContext.Instance.AddNotification(new NotificationBase(){..})
```

Inside a middleware, we are waiting on the `Response.OnStarting()` event and then we take all messages from the `NotificationHandler` and add them the response header:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var e = NotificationExecutionContext.Instance; // Required so that notification handler will be created in this context

    context.Response.OnStarting((state) =>
    {
        List<NotificationBase> notifications = NotificationExecutionContext.Instance.Notifications;
        if (notifications.Count > 0)
        {
            string messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notifications, Formatting.None);
            context.Response.Headers.Add("NotificationHeader", messageString);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }, null);

    await Next(context);
}
```

This code works, but are there pitfalls that we do not know? Or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** use static singletons like that. Having static dependencies like that inside your code defeats the whole purpose of dependency injection. You should just embrace dependency injection here, which would make this super simple:

```
/* in Startup.ConfigureServices */
// register the notification handler as a scoped dependency, this automatically makes the
// instance shared per request but not outside of it
services.AddScoped<INotificationHandler, NotificationHandler>();

/* in Startup.Configure */
// register your custom middleware
app.Use<NotificationHandlerMiddleware>();
```

```
public class NotificationHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly NotificationHandler _notificationHandler;

    public NotificationHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, INotificationHandler notificationHandler)
    {
        _next = next;
        _notificationHandler = notificationHandler;
    }

    public void Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // do whatever with _notificationHandler

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

And that’s all. No need to introduce statics, but using full dependency injection making your code completely testable and all dependencies clear.

> We tried to use it without dependency injection because if we have multiple different services we will have to many parameters in the constructors.

Too many constructor parameters is a clear sign for a violation of the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). If you find your services take many dependencies, you should consider splitting it up. You may also want to consider [refactoring to facade services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/).